# Log of driver adds/changes in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

I've been getting blue screens on my Windows 10 machine.  Is there a log I can see when and which hardware drivers were installed?  I wonder if there is a problem driver, so if I can correlate it to the date the blue screens started, that would be a good clue.

Comment: [analyze the dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) to see why you get a BSOD. if you need help, share the dmp file via OneDrive

Comment: s there a log I can see when and which hardware drivers were installed?

Comment: msinfo32 shows a list, but to really see the cause analyze the dumps with windbg